# I am using Unbound 5 DropDownList to display a list of collage course.how i retrieved stored data in these dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Unbound 5 Drop Down List to display a list of collage course.how i retrieved stored data in these  Unbound drop down list  when user log in in second time.i used sql data source  for these drop down list.

```
public partial class StudentExamDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=loki-pc;Initial Catalog=HpuRusa;User ID=sa;Password=admin");
    SqlDataReader dr;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        if (Page.IsPostBack ==false)
        {
            if (Session["name"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Loginfrm.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                con1.Open();

                  SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from TblExamDetails where UserId='" + Session["uid"] + "'", con1);
                  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                  da.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    ddlstream.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString().Trim(); ;
                    ddlmajorsub.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString().Trim();
                    ddlmajorsub1.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                    ddlmajorsub2.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
                    ddlminor1.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();
                    ddlminor1sub.Text = dt.Rows[0][6].ToString();
                    ddlminor2.Text = dt.Rows[0][7].ToString();
                    ddlminor2sub.Text = dt.Rows[0][8].ToString();
                    ddlcompulsory.Text = dt.Rows[0][9].ToString();
                    ddlcompusoryskill.Text = dt.Rows[0][10].ToString();
                    ddlgeneralsub.Text = dt.Rows[0][11].ToString();
                }
              }
            }

enter code here
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con1.Open();


        string stream = ddlstream.SelectedValue;
        string major = ddlmajorsub.SelectedValue;
        string major1 = ddlmajorsub1.SelectedValue;
        string major2 = ddlmajorsub2.SelectedValue;
        string minor1 = ddlminor1.SelectedValue;
        string minor1sub = ddlminor1sub.SelectedValue;
        string minor2 = ddlminor2.SelectedValue;
        string minor2sub = ddlminor2sub.SelectedValue;
        string com1 = ddlcompulsory.SelectedValue;
        string com2 = ddlcompusoryskill.SelectedValue;
        string gen = ddlgeneralsub.SelectedValue;


        SqlCommand cmd = con1.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "insertExam";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["uid"];
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Degree",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =stream;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MajorSubject",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =major;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Major1Subject",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =major1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Major2Subject",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = major2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Minor1",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =minor1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Minor1Subject",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =minor1sub;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Minor2",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = minor2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Minor2Subject",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =minor2sub;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompulsorySubject",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =com1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompulsorySkillSubject",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =com2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@GeneralSubject",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = gen;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con1.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Any exception or error message?

Comment: no exception or error message.only first drop down show the select data other drop down are display null.